# QGIS not syncing with Mergin

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

[image]

Four different location surveys were downloaded from Mergin to QGIS last week, today there are only two on the Mergin app and four on QGIS. The Mergin sync icon on QGIS is a light tone and not working?

[image: screenshot of Qgis]

Screenshot 2024-03-13 at 15.26.24

024-03-13T15:35:05     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis_gee_data_catalog/**init**.py", line 33, in classFactory
from .qgis_gee_data_catalog import GeeDataCatalog
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis_gee_data_catalog/qgis_gee_data_catalog.py", line 26, in
from .ee_interface import (add_ee_image_layer, download_ee_image_layer,
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis_gee_data_catalog/ee_interface.py", line 6, in
import ee
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ee'

2024-03-13T16:40:56     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/data.py", line 326, in _execute_cloud_call
return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:

```
         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
         
         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/__init__.py", line 42, in __wrapping_ee_import__
          _module_.Initialize(http_transport=httplib2.Http())
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/__init__.py", line 140, in Initialize
          ApiFunction.initialize()
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/apifunction.py", line 154, in initialize
          signatures = data.getAlgorithms()
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/data.py", line 1128, in getAlgorithms
          return _cloud_api_utils.convert_algorithms(_execute_cloud_call(call))
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/data.py", line 328, in _execute_cloud_call
          raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
         ee.ee_exception.EEException: Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access
         
         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
         
         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/data.py", line 326, in _execute_cloud_call
          return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
          return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
          raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
         googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: 
         
         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
         
         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/ee_plugin.py", line 125, in updateLayers
          import ee
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/__init__.py", line 46, in __wrapping_ee_import__
          _module_.Initialize(http_transport=httplib2.Http())
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/__init__.py", line 140, in Initialize
          ApiFunction.initialize()
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/apifunction.py", line 154, in initialize
          signatures = data.getAlgorithms()
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/data.py", line 1128, in getAlgorithms
          return _cloud_api_utils.convert_algorithms(_execute_cloud_call(call))
          File "/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/extlibs_darwin/ee/data.py", line 328, in _execute_cloud_call
          raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
         ee.ee_exception.EEException: Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access
```

Comment: Always present error messages as text in the body of the Question. There are two reasons: 1) Images are not legible on all devices, and 2) Images cannot be searched by others looking for your solution. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, how do i do that please?